# File of a specific month and year

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to create a Windows batch script that allows me to write filenames of a given directory to a text file only if the modification date is of a specific month and a specific year.
For example, how can I print all the files modified in May 2018 of the C:\tmp directory?

At the moment I wrote this instruction:

```
FORFILES /P C:\tmp /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE set fdate=@fdate& (call echo @path) >> file.txt" >NUL 2>&1
```

I should add these conditions:

```
if %fdate:~3,2%==05 if %fdate:~6,4%==2018
```

Comment: Why is `ForFiles` a requirement? You could, for instance, try `RoboCopy` for this task, `@For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('RoboCopy "C:\tmp" NULL /L /MaxAge:20180501 /MinAge:20180531 /NDL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS')Do @Echo(%%~nxA`.

Comment: Hi Compo, I can't figure out how to use the command line statement you indicated.

Comment: Oh thank you, before I had copied with @ in front. Now the instruction works. 
Just a curiosity, is it possible to achieve the same result with the instruction FORFILES and the conditions I indicated?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to delete my comments and post the pertinent parts as an answer:

If you wish to restrict your task to using [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles), you could try something like this from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), *(which would write the `file.txt` to the same directory as your batch file)*:

```bat
@CD /D "C:\tmp"
@FORFILES /D 01/05/2018 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE FORFILES /D -31/05/2018 /M @file /C 0x22cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE Echo @fdate @ftime @path0x22" 2>nul >>"%~dp0file.txt"
```

If you wanted to make your command more efficient, [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) may be a better option, *(the following writing `file.txt` to the current directory)*:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('RoboCopy "C:\tmp" NULL /L /MaxAge:20180501 /MinAge:20180531 /NDL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /TS')Do @Echo(%%A>>"file.txt"
```

The `For` loop is only required to remove the leading space padding from the output, if you don't care about that, you can simply use:

```bat
@RoboCopy "C:\tmp" NULL /L /MaxAge:20180501 /MinAge:20180531 /NDL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /TS>"file.txt"
```

Comment: @alberto89, you'd need to tell us more. Perhaps my `For` example failed when you changed something, like perhaps when you decided to substitute `C:\tmp` with `SomePath\ ` instead of `SomePath`

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I tried the code in prompt with %%a instead of %a. I don't know the batch script sytanx very well. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: @alberto89, you asked a question using the [tag:batch-file] tag and where you specifically mentioned batch script. I provided batch file/script answers, they are complete batch files, you do not add, remove or change anything. You paste them as they are into a blank notepad document and save as `test1.cmd`, `test2.cmd` and `test3.cmd`, then double click each in turn to check the output.

Comment: Ok, but initially I didn't know that there were syntactical differences between a batch script and the command launched manually. Thank you for your support.